# Intersection of a set and list of dictionaries

Tags: python-2.7

I have a set `my_set = ("a","b","c","d","z")` and a list `my_list=[{"a",0.5},{"c",0.6},{"b",0.9},{"z",0.5},{"m",0.0}]`. I would like to have a list with items containing keys in `my_set` only. In this case the result I would like to have is `new_list=[{"a",0.5},{"c",0.6},{"b",0.9},{"z",0.5}]`

The list and set is large. Is there an efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: it appears that `"z"` appears in both `my_set` and `my_list`, but you omitted `"z"` from your desired output...should you have included `{"z",0.5} in `new_list`?

Comment: @gariepy,  Thanks, you are right. I have made correction in the question.

Comment: Is this a list of _dict_, or a list of _set_? Currently it looks like list of set. If it's list of dict, why not use a single dict instead? And could those dicts (or sets) ever contain more than one of the keys?

Comment: @tobias_k Actually, I am reading a csv file. Each key and value pairs in my_list are rows of the csv file. I might have used wrong data structure. But I would like to have a list of key and value pair for the keys in the my_set. The csv file has 1000s of rows. Suggestion for correct data structure and a way to implement it will be highly appreciated. Also the keys are unique in my_list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that that's actually a set and a list of dicts, as stated in the question, you can try this:

```
In [1]: my_set = set(["a","b","c","d","z"])
In [2]: my_list=[{"a":0.5},{"c":0.6},{"b":0.9},{"z":0.5},{"m":0.0}]
In [3]: [d for d in my_list if all(k in my_set for k in d)]
Out[3]: [{'a': 0.5}, {'c': 0.6}, {'b': 0.9}, {'z': 0.5}]
```

This simply uses a list comprehension to check that all the keys in the dicts are contained in the set.  This will have complexity of O(nm), for n dicts in the list, with m keys each (m being 1 in your case) and assuming that set-lookup is always O(1).

Note, however, that you do not really need a list of dictionaries, since all the keys seem to be different (in this example, at least), so a single dictionary would be enough.